# Переклад фразеологізму "пробу ставить негде"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Необхідно перекласти вислів "Да на нем пробу ставить негде!" (у контексті мається на увазі, що людина погана, мерзенна).

На жаль, віднайти якихось відповідників не вдалося, навіть у [російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів (1959 р.)](https://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%20%281959%29.pdf).

Однак, у кількох творах сучасних письменників побачив, що перекладається вираз "[пробу ставить негде](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/38306/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5)" дослівно як "пробу ставити ніде", для прикладу - [витяг з книги А. Кокотюхи "Червоний"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=4_gnDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT43&lpg=PT43&dq=%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=Bj7u8eLoQp&sig=ACfU3U0PJ7A_XVjVsnO1-zs6mgoCabkmpw&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikuKTXlNzzAhWL-ioKHX0fAdgQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&f=false):

> Ви мене, русака, на якому **проби ніде ставити**, хочете записати у бандерівці?

Або ж із книги ["Казки для дорослих" О. Калини](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=yySjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&lpg=PT7&dq=%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=dhEVyG5k5S&sig=ACfU3U1NuYY5mX7khBkEG-4e29k5EX-36w&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikuKTXlNzzAhWL-ioKHX0fAdgQ6AF6BAgREAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&f=false):

> На ньому ж **проби ставити ніде**: скрізь він бував, все знає, все бачив, руки по лікоть в крові.

Чи коректно буде перекласти цей вислів дослівно?

Comment: Замість "проби" є ще клеймо або тавро, наприклад: [Ніде клейма ставити: чому такі гіганти як Scania не дбають про свою репутацію в Україні](https://www.unn.com.ua/uk/news/1938351-nide-kleyma-staviti-chomu-taki-giganti-yak-scania-ne-dbayut-pro-svoyu-reputatsiyu-v-ukrayini)